# Automating library build

Tags: iphone, xcode, build-process, build-automation

I don't have any experience tweaking Xcode build scripts.  I've created a static library.  When the referencing app builds for debug simulator, I have to make sure the library also has a recent debug simulator build, rather than say device debug.   Is there a way to build in the referencing project and have the static library automatically build the same configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help will help you.

http://www.mobileorchard.com/code-sharing-via-static-libraries-and-cross-project-references/

Thierry